# Converting an Input XML to OTHER XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-serialization, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting input xml using xslt to other XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286748/converting-input-xml-using-xslt-to-other-xml)

I am astarter in XSLT. I have looked some codes for the task i was interested on and built some logic but i could not get into the desired output. I am glad if i could get a help.

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<t>
<Data>
    <CD>
        <Artist>xxx.yyy</Artist>
        <song>abc</song>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <Artist>xxx.zzz</Artist>
        <song>cba</song>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <Artist>aaa.kkk</Artist>
        <song>123</song>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <Artist>aaa.lll</Artist>
        <song>456</song>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <Artist>ddd</Artist>
        <song>1234</song>
    </CD>
</Data>
<Music>
    <music_no>E123</music_no>
    <music_type>outdoor</music_type>
    <Artist>bat.ball</Artist>
    <value>0000</value>
</Music>
<Music>
    <music_no>E123</music_no>
    <music_type>outdoor</music_type>
    <Artist>bat.stone</Artist>
    <value>0001</value>
</Music>
<Music>
    <music_no>E111</music_no>
    <music_type>outdoor</music_type>
    <Artist>board.coins</Artist>
    <value>0002</value>
</Music>
<Music>
    <music_no>E111</music_no>
    <music_type>outdoor</music_type>
    <Artist>board.ball</Artist>
    <value>0003</value>
</Music>
<Music>
    <music_no>E001</music_no>
    <music_type>indoor</music_type>
    <Artist>bat.ball</Artist>
    <value>8888</value>
</Music>
<Music>
    <music_no>E001</music_no>
    <music_type>indoor</music_type>
    <Artist>bat.stone</Artist>
    <value>9999</value>
</Music>
<Music>
    <music_no>E111</music_no>
    <music_type>indoor</music_type>
    <Artist>board.coins</Artist>
    <value>0001</value>
</Music>
<Music>
    <music_no>E111</music_no>
    <music_type>indoor</music_type>
    <Artist>bat</Artist>
    <value>0001</value>
</Music>
</t>
```

Expected Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<version_3>
<information>
    <xxx>
        <yyy>abc</yyy>
        <zzz>cba</zzz>
    </xxx>
    <aaa>
        <kkk>123</kkk>
        <lll>456</lll>
    </aaa>
    <ddd>1234</ddd>
</information>
<information>
    <bat>
        <ball>0000</ball>
        <stone>0001</stone>
    </bat>
    <board>
        <coins>0002</coins>
        <ball>0003</ball>
    </board>
    <bat>
        <ball>8888</ball>
        <stone>9999</stone>
    </bat>
    <board>
        <coins>0001</coins>
    </board>
</information>
<information>
    <bat>0001</bat>
</information>
 </version_3>
```

Edited Expected Output:

```
Expected Output:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<version_3>
<information>
    <xxx>
        <yyy>abc</yyy>
        <zzz>cba</zzz>
    </xxx>
    <aaa>
        <kkk>123</kkk>
        <lll>456</lll>
    </aaa>
    <ddd>1234</ddd>
</information>
<information>
    <bat>
        <ball>0000</ball>
        <stone>0001</stone>
    </bat>
</information>
<information>
    <board>
        <coins>0002</coins>
        <ball>0003</ball>
    </board>
    <board>
        <coins>0001</coins>
                          <bat>0001</bat>
    </board>
</information>
<information>
    <bat>
        <ball>8888</ball>
        <stone>9999</stone>
    </bat>
      </information>
   </version_3>
```

In the above Input XML: you can notice "CD" element and values in it, similarly "music". I want to get an output that looks like,

Sample output for "CD":

```
<information>
    <xxx>
        <yyy>abc</yyy>
        <zzz>cba</zzz>
    </xxx>
    <aaa>
        <kkk>123</kkk>
        <lll>456</lll>
    </aaa>
    <ddd>1234</ddd>
</information>
```

I could Achieve this to some extent by Muenchian Grouping. But,

The next Element "Music" has sub elements in which, the first two elements "music_no" & "music_type" get matched then the Values in the "Artist" has to be grouped. If they arent matched they have to be seperately grouped.

Sample o/p for Music:

```
<information>
    <bat>
        <ball>0000</ball>
        <stone>0001</stone>
    </bat>
    <board>
        <coins>0002</coins>
        <ball>0003</ball>
    </board>
    <bat>
        <ball>8888</ball>
        <stone>9999</stone>
    </bat>
    <board>
        <coins>0001</coins>
    </board>
</information>
<information>
    <bat>0001</bat>
</information>
```

I could not achieve the second part as it is bit tricky with iterations. Help is Appreciated.

Note: for the "Music" element if the Value in the Artist resembles the same with the corresponding nodes but having no "." then that Value has to be seperately grouped that is outside "information" and shall have new "information"

My Code that i Worked on:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"            xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
<xsl:key name="kBychildName" match="CD" use="name(Artist/*[1])"/>
<xsl:key name="kByAttribs" match="Artist" use="concat(../@music_no, '+', ../@music_type)"/>
<xsl:key name="kChildByAttribsAndArtist" match="Artist/*" use="concat(../../@music_no, '+', ../../@music_type, '+', name())"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <version_3>
        <information>
            <xsl:variable name="var1">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="pass2" select="ext:node-set($var1)/* [generate-id()=generate-id(key('kBychildName',name(Artist/*[1]))[1]) or not(Artist/*)]"/>
        </information>
        <information>
            <xsl:variable name="var2">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="pass3" select="ext:node-set($var2)/*/* [generate-id() = generate-id(key('kByAttribs', concat(../@music_no, '+', ../@music_type) ) [1])] "/>
        </information>
    </version_3>
    <!--xsl:copy-of select="//msg_debug"/-->
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="CD[contains(Artist,'.')]">
    <CD>
        <Artist>
            <xsl:element name="{substring-before(Artist, '.')}">
                <xsl:element name="{substring-after(Artist, '.')}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="song"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </Artist>
    </CD>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="CD">
    <CD>
        <Artist>
            <xsl:element name="{Artist}">
                <xsl:value-of select="song"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </Artist>
    </CD>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="CD" mode="pass2">
<xsl:apply-templates select="*/*[1]" mode="pass2"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Artist/*" mode="pass2">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="self::*[not(*)]/text()|key('kBychildName', name())/*/*/*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Music[contains(Artist, '.')]">
    <Music music_no="{music_no}" music_type="{music_type}">
        <Artist>
            <xsl:element name="{substring-before(Artist, '.')}">
                <xsl:element name="{substring-after(Artist, '.')}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </Artist>
    </Music>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Music">
    <Music music_no="{music_no}" music_type="{music_type}">
        <Artist>
            <xsl:element name="{Artist}">
                <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </Artist>
    </Music>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Artist" mode="pass3">
    <!--Artist-->
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="pass3" select="*[generate-id() =generate-id(key('kChildByAttribsAndArtist', concat(../../@music_no, '+', ../../@music_type,'+', name()))[1] ) ]"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('kByAttribs',concat(../@music_no, '+', ../@music_type) )/*[not(*)] "/>
    <!--/Artist-->
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Artist/*" mode="pass3">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('kChildByAttribsAndArtist', concat(../../@music_no, '+', ../../@music_type, '+', name()) )/* "/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am glad to explain the problem again, if found difficult. As a beginners to XSLT i hope you can help me.

Comment: This is a well asked question. You've specified a broad range, but not too complex input, expected output and a work-in-progress style-sheet. We don't get many well asked questions, so congradulations!

Comment: Variants of this question have been circulating here for some time. Aren't you the same person posting these questions under different user-ids? I would alert the moderators about this unwanted activity. -1.

Comment: To Moderators: I believe that `Ramana` and `user1510890` are two different userIds used by the same physical person. This person has been proliferating very similar questions under different user-ids. I think you may be interested in this activity.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin: Please, read my comments above and be aware.

Comment: @Ruser1510890: Oh, you changed your userid? Again? How did it happen that you use exactly my solution to exactly the same problem? Even if you aren't "Ramana", this is a duplicate question. I am tired of seeing variations of the same question over and over again -- this serves no purpose other that gaining enough rep for a dummy account in order to be able to upvote/downvote from it.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: I thought that cases like this would be interesting to a moderator.

Comment: @Dimitre: I am not trying to achieve Fame or reputation, i was trying to learn XSLT as i couldn't achieve the o/p. I googled to find solution and directed to StackOverflow.

Comment: @Ruser1510890: Then how can you explain that this is a question that was already asked and you are providing *my* solution saying: "My Code that i Worked on"? If you found an existing question and have questions about it, you need to provide a link to that question and also provide a link to the solution that you are trying to use, and ethics requires to say *whose* solution this is. If you have modified this solution, again ethics requires to say that this is your modification of the solution provided by this SO user to this question. Or is this a homework that 20+ students have? Then say so!

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: I have been developing an application that has input coming from database dynamically. I thought to develop an xslt that converts the input xml in such a format that i can read. I googled: Muenchian Grouping converting input xml to other xml. I have been redirected to a page in StackOverflow. After getting to that code i thought it would be better to post and done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple question deserves a simple answer. This XSLT 1.0 style-sheet ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="artist-group" match="CD|Music" use="
      concat( substring-before(Artist,'.'),'|',music_no,'|',music_type)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <version_3>

   <information> 
     <xsl:apply-templates select="t/Data/CD
     [generate-id(.) = generate-id( key('artist-group',
       concat( substring-before(Artist,'.'),'||'))[1])]
     [substring-before(Artist,'.')]" />
     <xsl:apply-templates select="key('artist-group','||')/self::CD" />
   </information> 

   <information> 
     <xsl:apply-templates select="t/Music
     [generate-id(.) = generate-id( key('artist-group',
       concat( substring-before(Artist,'.'),'|',music_no,'|',music_type))[1])]
     [substring-before(Artist,'.')]" />
   </information> 

   <information> 
     <xsl:apply-templates select="t/Music[substring-before(Artist,'.') = '']" />
   </information> 

  </version_3>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CD[ substring-before(Artist,'.') != ''] |
                  Music[ substring-before(Artist,'.') != '']">
 <xsl:element name="{substring-before(Artist,'.')}">
  <xsl:for-each select="key('artist-group',
     concat( substring-before(Artist,'.'),'|',music_no,'|',music_type))" >
   <xsl:element name="{substring-after(Artist,'.')}">
    <xsl:value-of select="song|value" /> 
   </xsl:element>  
  </xsl:for-each> 
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="CD[ substring-before(Artist,'.')  = ''] |
                  Music[ substring-before(Artist,'.')  = '']">
 <xsl:element name="{Artist}">
  <xsl:value-of select="song|value" /> 
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... when applied to your sample input, will produce your required expected output.

### Explanation

A single key is used to group both Music and CD elements. In the case of music, there is a further division into music_no and music_type. The first output information node is derived from a muenchian grouping of the CD elements. The orphaned artists within the first information node are produced by the   instruction.

A common pair CD|Music templates is used for all grouped-artists and orphaned-artists node production. The first of the template pair, with predicate [substring-before(Artist,'.')!=''] is used for the grouped-artists, and the other for the orphaned artists.

The production of the second information node, goes like the first, except it is based on input Music nodes and excludes orphaned artists.

The production of the third information node is derived from orphaned Music nodes.

By 'orphaned', I mean nodes whose Artist value does not contain a dot character.

Comment: Hi, I understand the logic and want to appreciate your guidance. Thank You Sean. When i run the code you have provided. I did not get o/p values in it. Can u help me showing the output you got. My Output shows : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><version_3>
<information>
<ddd>1234</ddd>
</information>
<information/>
<information/>
</version_3>

Comment: I understand what have gone wrong. I got the values now. Thank you.

Comment: @user1510890: Are you Ramana? http://stackoverflow.com/users/1494894/ramana

Comment: What if in the input element "Music" if i want to group element value having "music_no" identical to one "information" element and the other values to other "information" element. Example: im editing my output or simply adding other output differed from the first one.

Comment: & All Experience Users. Thanks for your guidance. I have cleared the issue that i was looking. I am posting my code that i have slightly modified that well suits the edited xml output. Once again thanks.

Comment: <xsl:key name="musictest" match="Music" use="music_no"/>                                                     <xsl:for-each select="//t/Music[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('musictest', music_no)[1])] ">
<information>
<xsl:variable name="MusicInfo" select="music_no"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="//t/Music[generate-id(.) = generate-id( key('artist-group',        concat( substring-before(Artist ,'.'),'|',$MusicInfo,'|',music_type))[1])] [substring-before(Artist ,'.') or not(Artist/*)]"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('artist-group','||')/self::Music"/>
</information>
</xsl:for-each>